# Stripe id_number and ssn_last_4 error message

Tags: stripe-payments, stripes

We outsourced the development of our app. During testing, we entered real bank information into the Stripe form, we keep getting this error message

"cannot provide both id_number and ssn_last_4 unless they match"

Developers have not been able to fix this error. What are we doing wrong?

Please help

After filling the Stripe ACH form, I was expecting to successfully submit the bank information to complete the registration of my profile on the platform.

Comment: have you validated what your code is passing in as the `id_number` and `ssn_last_4`? As the error message mentions, if you're passing in both, they need to match.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.